# Create a new json response based on existing response

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have the json response with value week1,week2,week3,week4 in week key along with count based on category (meetingHash)and week wise.I tried to merge with .reduce but no luck.

Now creating 2 rows for the user if I have `week1 and week2` for `meetingHash 'Hold/Uncategorized'` for the `user Sarathy Devaraju` in `month may`.

But i want to combine as { meetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", month: "May", UserName: "Sarathy Devaraju", Week1: 2, Week2: 0, Week3: 3, Week4: 0 }

expected as

```
[{"UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju","month":"May","meetingHash":"Hold/Uncategorized","Week1":2,"Week2":0,"Week3":3,"Week4":0},
          {"UserName":"Priya","month":"May","meetingHash":"Hold/Uncategorized","Week1":2,"Week2":0,"Week3":0,"Week4":0},
          {"UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju","month":"May","meetingHash":"1st Presentation / Meeting","Week1":0,"Week2":1,"Week3":0,"Week4":0},
          {"UserName":"Priya","month":"May","meetingHash":"1st Presentation / Meeting","Week1":0,"Week2":1,"Week3":0,"Week4":0},
          {"UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju","month":"Jun","meetingHash":"1st Presentation / Meeting","Week1":0,"Week2":1,"Week3":0,"Week4":0},
          {"UserName":"Priya","month":"Jun","meetingHash":"1st Presentation / Meeting","Week1":0,"Week2":1,"Week3":0,"Week4":0},
          {"UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju","month":"Jun","meetingHash":"Follow-On Meetings","Week1":1,"Week2":0,"Week3":0,"Week4":0},
          {"UserName":"Priya","month":"Jun","meetingHash":"Follow-On Meetings","Week1":1,"Week2":0,"Week3":0,"Week4":0},
          {"UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju","month":"Jul","meetingHash":"Follow-On Meetings","Week1":0,"Week2":0,"Week3":1,"Week4":0},
          {"UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju","month":"Jul","meetingHash":"Follow-On Meetings","Week1":1,"Week2":0,"Week3":0,"Week4":0},
         ]
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 2
    },
     {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
        "monthinwords": "Jun",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
        "monthinwords": "Jun",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 3",
        "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
        "monthinwords": "July",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
        "monthinwords": "Jun",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
        "monthinwords": "Jun",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
        "monthinwords": "July",
        "count": 1
    }
];

const WEEKS = ["Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4"];

const result = data.map(obj => {
        return {
            UserName: obj.UserName,
            month: obj.monthinwords,
            meetingHash: obj.MeetingHash,
            Week1: WEEKS.indexOf(obj.week) == 0 ? obj.count : 0,
            Week2: WEEKS.indexOf(obj.week) == 1 ? obj.count : 0,
            Week3: WEEKS.indexOf(obj.week) == 2 ? obj.count : 0,
            Week4: WEEKS.indexOf(obj.week) == 3 ? obj.count : 0,
        }
    }
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: please check my updated post

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171480/recreate-a-json-response-based-on-existing-response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [recreate a json response based on existing response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171480/recreate-a-json-response-based-on-existing-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 2
    },
     {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
        "monthinwords": "Jun",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
        "monthinwords": "Jun",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Sarathy Devaraju",
        "week": "Week 3",
        "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
        "monthinwords": "July",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Hold/Uncategorized",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
        "monthinwords": "Jun",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
        "monthinwords": "Jun",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 2",
        "MeetingHash": "1st Presentation / Meeting",
        "monthinwords": "May",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Priya",
        "week": "Week 1",
        "MeetingHash": "Follow-On Meetings",
        "monthinwords": "July",
        "count": 1
    }
];

const item = {}
data.forEach(obj => {
          const key =`${obj.MeetingHash}_${obj.UserName}_${obj.monthinwords}`
              if(!item[key]) { 
                  item[key] = {
                    "Week 1": 0,
                     "Week 2": 0,
                      "Week 3": 0,
                       "Week 4": 0,
                  }
                }
      
              item[key]["UserName"] = obj.UserName
              item[key]["meetingHash"] = obj.MeetingHash
              item[key]["month"] =  obj.monthinwords
              item[key][obj.week] = obj.count

            }
);
const temp = []
Object.keys(item).forEach(record => {
    temp.push(item[record])
})
console.log(temp)
```

Comment: is it possible to place weeks below month

Comment: In Js object doesn't store key in order.  No it is not possible to place the weeks before month in object.

It will not impact on how you read the data. It will be always according to the passed key.